# IIS7 File already in use

Tags: iis

Recently I've installed IIS7, but when I try to edit ANY file inside my wwwroot and save it it keeps giving me an error 'can't save file, file is already in use'. Even if I make a new .txt file and try to save it I get the same error. It's really getting annoying.
Been trying alot but I really can't figure out.

Comment: You can use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx to see what process is locking all of the files. In my experience IIS doesn't do this, even with code files because it compiles them to a temp folder and reads from there. Unless your app is opening and not releasing the files something else is.

Answer (score 0):

Stop your website in IIS Manager if you want to edit the files.

A better approach in the long run is to use FTP to edit your files rather than working directly on your web server.